# Using 5-star CSS solution, when screen under 330px line wraps and cannot click second row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a 5-star rating system designed to be used on mobile devices.  On most phones it works fine, but sometimes a phone's width registers as less than 330px which causes the row of stars to wrap, like so:

[image]

If you click on the 5th star, however, it won't register.  The "box" is still on the previous row.

Here's a JS fiddle where you can see it in effect by dragging the bottom-right-hand-side render box's width: http://jsfiddle.net/yqj3bjLf/1/

And here is the relevant CSS:

```
/* Change span immediately following the checked radio */
.rating input:checked + span {
    /*background-position: -22px 0;**
    background-position: -145px 0;*/
    background-position: -58px 0;
}

/* Reset all remaining stars back to default background.
   This supersedes the above due to its ordering. */

.rating input:checked + span ~ span {
    background-position: 0 0;
}

.star-grey:before {
    content: "\f000";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    color: grey;
}

.star-yellow:before {
    content: "\f000";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    color: #ffe43e;
}
```

How can I fix prevent this?  I've tried applying my own CSS, but the `:before` CSS classes don't seem to be taking when I try to effect them with new, page-specific inline `@media` queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy, set `display` for the container to `inline-block` and set `white-space` to `nowrap`. Should work. I had the same issue.

edit:

```
.rating {
  display: inline-block !important;
  white-space: nowrap !important;
}
```

This is the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/yqj3bjLf/7/

Comment: No dash. It's `nowrap` rather than `no-wrap` and set it to container. I gave you the code.

Comment: Also check if you really need `!important`. Shouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest setting the min-width of the .rating container to at least 75px. I tried the above solutions and some other I found, but this worked for me.